# How to split array values into new lines - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that looks like this

array_names = [Mathew,Kelp ,Liman Kolf, Hebert,Ansh];

Now in the array above, `Mathew, Kelp` is one name , `Liman Kolf` is another name and `Herbet,Ansh` is another name making it 3 names in the array.

Now i want to split this array on new lines in table like below

```
Mathew,Kelp
Liman Kolf
Herbet,Ansh
```

But with my code as shown below, the table is represented like this

```
Mathew 
Kelp 
Liman Kolf
Herbet
Ansh
```

**JS**

```
//how i save to localstorage
 $("#myTableID").on("click", "#add-contact", function() { 
        var values = [];
        value = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('#user-id').text();
        values.push(value);
        localStorage.setItem('contact_list', values);


}

var array_names = localStorage.getItem('contact_list').split(',');
if(array_names.length)
                {
                    $.each(array_names, function(index, value){
                        $('#myTableID2').append('<tr><td id="contact">'+value+'</td></tr>');
                 });
                }
```

**Controller**

```
$contacts = Contact::where('firstname','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('lastname','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
```

Comment: if Mathew and kelp is one name then why there is `,` in between both of the items

Comment: That is how the names are stored in the database @JuhilSomaiya

Comment: When extracting from the database, you should get a list of _strings_: ```["Mathew,Kelp", "Liman Kolf", "Hebert,Ansh"]```. Otherwise, there's no way to tell if the ```,``` is the separator or part of the name.

Comment: @Moutah, how do i separate the string you have in your comment ?

Comment: How do you retrieve the list of names? In your code you get them from ```localStorage```, how to they end up there?

Comment: @RoboPHP where  you are storing values of array `array_names`

Comment: @Moutah, i store the values from the database in a localStorage. And i retrieve them as shown above

Comment: @MayankVadiya these values are in the localstorage with key `contact_list`

Comment: @RoboPHP Please show your full code with how you are saving in localstorage

Comment: Can you show us the code that gets them from the database and store the in localStorage?

Comment: @MayankVadiya Check the update, please

Comment: @Moutah, check update, please

Comment: You might find it easier if you use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) when storing the values array and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) when retrieving it. Or, at the very least, do a `values.join(';')` so that you can split it later on semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split them by a `RegExp`

```
const string = 'Mathew,Kelp ,Liman Kolf, Hebert,Ansh';
const array = string.split(/(?: ,)|(?:, )/)
// ["Mathew,Kelp", "Liman Kolf, Hebert,Ansh"]
```

Comment: While this would work for this specific case, relying on the space around ```,``` to split the string is dodgy. What if a name suddently has a space?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Khauri, use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`  to read/write from/to `localStorage`:

```js
// save values to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('contact_list', JSON.stringify(values));

// retrive values from localStorage
var array_names = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('contact_list'));

// do things with the values
if (array_names.length) {
    $.each(array_names, function (index, value) {
        $('#myTableID2').append('<tr><td id="contact">' + value + '</td></tr>');
    });
}
```